# Displaying Json Data in Cocoa Application Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm a newbie to either Swift and Objective-C.
I'm developing a mac application that will display a list of items.
What is the best way to do this, and if I could ask for sample codes that will be awesome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Google or Stackoverflow search!
You won`t get sample code here if you do not show us what you already tried. There are tons of tutorials out there to start programming with.

- [Parse JSON](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/)
- [Tableview for OSX](http://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial)